# Is there any data on NHibernate vs Fluent NHibernate startup performance?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In short, what works faster:

- SessionFactory precompiling XML
  configuration, or
- Fluent NHibernate providing
  configuration programmatically ?

Comment: Why do you care about the difference? It should be a small fraction of a second, or takes it longer in your case?

Comment: Just didn't know how Fluent NHibernate works, thought that it could be more efficient than parcing XML configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluent NHIbernate creates the XML documents and Sessionfactory under the hood, so it is slower than not using Fluent NHibernate.

Why do you ask?

Comment: I didn't know that Fluent NHibernate creates XML document, I though it maybe using some internal API to generate prcompiled mapping.

Answer (score 8):

My personal experience has been that the building of the Configuration object (which is unavoidable* regardless of whether Fluent is used) generally dwarfs the time required to setup a FluentConfiguration object, with the factor increasing as the number of mappings increase.

On a 2.5 Ghz c2d, with my project with approximately 15 mappings, it took 360ms for FluentConfiguration, and 5215ms for Configuration.

On a test project with 1000 mappings (simple classes with 2-3 string properties), it took 470ms for FluentConfiguration, and 40336 (40 seconds!) for Configuration.

<sub>*Actually, not really. most of the cost of Configuration comes from validating the XML mappings. Ayende has discussed it [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/26/Real-World-NHibernate-Reducing-startup-times-for-large-amount-of.aspx) (as well as a quick speedup obtained from merging the mappings into a single file), and a possible alternative to building the configuration at application startup is to serialize it as discussed [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.aspx). In the 1000-mapping test project, this reduced the time required to get a Configuration object to around 30ms (although it has also increased the time required to build the SessionFactory from ~3 to ~4 seconds - I am unsure why).</sub>