# Fluent nHibernate Slow Startup Time

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, c#-4.0

I am using Fluent NHibernate and I like it !
I am having a little issue: The startup time is about 10 seconds and I don´t know how to optimize Fluent nHibernate
To make this startup time less problematic, I put it on a Thread.

Could somebody tell a solution to this? And reply with the code below modified to make the performance improvement?

I saw something like this on:
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.aspx
but I don´t know how to make this work together with Fluent nHibernate.

My code is like this:

```
public static ISession ObterSessao()        
{
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;

        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationHelper.LeConfiguracaoWeb("EstoqueDBNet"); // My Connection string goes here

        var config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(ConnectionString));

        config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        var session = config
            .BuildSessionFactory()
            .OpenSession();

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal;

        return session;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phill has the right answer, but to take it a little further take a look at  http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.html for serializing the NHibernate configuration to a file, so you don't have to rebuild it every time you start the app. This may or may not be a little faster depending on various factors (principally, number of mappings you have) - pursuant to this, [Is there any data on NHibernate vs Fluent NHibernate startup performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625597/is-there-any-data-on-nhibernate-vs-fluent-nhibernate-startup-performance/1794569#1794569)

Just to emphasize (based on some of your followup qns in answer-comments), you should be serializing the (NHibernate.Cfg.)Configuration object, not the SessionFactory.

Then, you use the `Fluently.Configure(Configuration cfg)` overload to inject the config when creating your FluentConfiguration (instead of having it automatically build one for you).

Comment: Yes! That is one point I was missing: Fluently.Configure(Configuration cfg) ; To Finish this Question I think I need just another point: How to do the reverse: Access the NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration from the Fluent nHibernate? With this I will be able to Serialize  and Deserialize.

Comment: I am trying to do this. At this step of getting the Configuration for save via Serializing I am having this error:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration' to 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration'

Comment: Hey! It worked. I used this to do the reverse: NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = config.BuildConfiguration(); // config is FluentConfiguration

Comment: @Tony, I assume you have gotten the problem fixed but if not, I don't quite understand your problem, so if you could post some sample code that demonstrates the error I'll be happy to take a look at it

Answer (score 5):

You only need to build the configuration once. At the moment you're building a new configuration every time you get a session.

Comment: Hi, how could I store the config object on a file, so when I run my program again, I can read it (Deserialize) and start the program fast? I tried to Serialize the config  object in the code above, but it only returned this:   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<FluentConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

Comment: You could put your code into a static constructor, and assign the SessionFactory to a static property that returns ISessionFactory. Then call obtersesao.OpenSession()

Comment: Is there someway to store (Serialize) the Factory in a file, and restore it later? Because my application is a Executable, and everytime the user runs it, there is the 10 second delay.

Comment: You might be able to reduce the startup time by putting your mapping in a different assembly. Using GetExecutingAssembly would be loading your applications assembly which might be large and take time to workout what needs to be mapped. If you had a seperate assembly with your say 15 mapping classes and nothing else. It would be much quicker. You might shave off 5 seconds, then whats 5 second start up? Pretty minor.

Comment: Here's a link that might be helpful after you've refactored your helper class. http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2010/03/31/speeding-up-nhibernate-startup-time.aspx

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't mess with the thread priority, if anything what you're doing will make it slower.

Second, like Phill said, you need to cache your SessionFactory or you'll be rebuilding the configuration every time you need a session object.

You could do something like this, or move the code in the `if` into the class' static constructor:

```
private static SessionFactory _factory = null;
public static ISession ObterSessao()        
{
    if(_factory == null) {
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationHelper.LeConfiguracaoWeb("EstoqueDBNet"); // My Connection string goes here

        var config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(ConnectionString));

        config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        _factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    return _factory.OpenSession();
}
```

Comment: How can i save this _factory to a file (Serialize) , and when my user the application again, i read the file, and restore (Deserialize) the _factory? Because the problem is the creation of the factory and my application run on client machine, so every time the user clicks, there is about 10 seconds delay.

Comment: @Tony, If there is truly a 10 second delay every time that your user clicks something then the problem isn't with the Fluent configuration, it must be somewhere else. By caching the SessionFactory you should only incur the mapping overhead once, during application startup. Is the 10 second delay you talk about only at startup?